# Uploading / using my component library to npmjs? (React + styled components + storybook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, styled-components

Do anyone have a guide on how to publish and use a npmjs package that is using styled-components?

If not, how do I upload my component library to npmjs? The caveat is that I'm using styled-components so I'm not sure how to configure my babel to work with this.
I have followed this guide: https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#i-am-a-library-author-should-i-bundle-styledcomponents-with-my-library
But when I tried using my package I got that my project is not exporting my-component.js.

So far this is my work:

**index.js**

```
import Button from './components/button/Button'
import Container from './components/container/Container'
import Grid from './components/grid/Grid'
import Heading from './components/heading/Heading'
import Image from './components/image/Image'
import Select from './components/select[WIP]/Select'
import Stack from './components/stack/Stack'
import Text from './components/text/Text'
import TextLink from './components/textLink/TextLink'
import ZIndex from './components/zIndex/ZIndex'

export {
  Button,
  Container,
  Grid,
  Heading,
  Image,
  Select,
  Stack,
  Text,
  TextLink,
  ZIndex,
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yaytrade",
  "version": "0.1.16",
  "license": "ISC",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "module": "build/index.module.js",
  "unpkg": "build/index.umd.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook -o .storybook-build",
    "start-storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -p 6006",
    "lint": "eslint --fix .",
    "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.json",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "chromatic": "npx chromatic --project-token=c5q00gcvr6d"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-idx": "^2.4.0",
    "idx": "^2.5.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.0.21",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.21",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-require": "^3.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.11.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chromatic": "^5.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.8.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^5.0.3",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "lint-staged": "^10.3.0",
    "microbundle": "^0.12.3",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "styled-components": ">= 5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "styled-components": ">= 5"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,scss}": [
      "npx prettier --write -c .prettierrc",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    "react-require",
    [
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      {
        "paths": [
          {
            "rootPathPrefix": "~",
            "rootPathSuffix": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: Your setup looks fine. Can you share your bundle files then?

Comment: Ok! Do you mean if I can share then with you or?
Otherwise, the problem is that I'm accessing them via the index.js file but it says that my component is not being exported from the package

Comment: Did you try to open the index file in repo consumer at `node_modules/<your-package>/build/index.js` to see if your component was exported accordingly?

Comment: I rebuilt everything so this question is not valid anymore, thanks anyways!

Comment: Cool. So you should close this question as well